# Implement custom logic after the graphql query has been parsed

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

Is there a way to implement custom logic right after the graphql query has been parsed, but before any of the resolvers have executed?

Given this query schema

```
type Query {
  products(...): ProductConnection!
  productByHandle(handle: String!): Product
}
```

How can I accomplish the task of logging the `info` object for the `products` and `productByHandle` queries, before their resolvers have had a chance to execute?

I'm basically looking to "hook up" to an imaginary event like `query:parsed`, but it doesn't appear to exist. I'm using the `express-graphql` package.

Comment: .... middleware?

Comment: I'm not sure what middleware you are talking about exactly. Express middleware does not  allow you to intercept the graphql parsing, it would just allow you to do something before/after the graphql endpoint, and one of the requirements here is that I have access to the parsed  graphql query, but intercept its execution.

Comment: hmmm, then some options https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#options ... `customExecuteFn` (before original) or `customParseFn` (after original) ?

Answer (score 1):

Props to @xadm for figuring this out.

`express-graphql` package accepts a custom execute function, which is the function that gets called after the query has been parsed. Its return value is what gets returned from the `/graphql` endpoint.

```js
import { graphHTTP } from 'express-graphql'
import { execute } from 'graphql'

app.use('/graphql', graphHTTP((req, res) => {
    return {
        ...,
        async customExecuteFn(ExecutionArgs) {
            // The `info` object is available on ExecutionArgs

            // { data: {...}, errors: [...] }
            const result = await execute(ExecutionArgs)

            return result
        }
    }
}))
```

I will still leave this here, as it might be useful for something more specific, but you should probably use the code above.

```js
// This returns an object, whose keys are the query names and the values are the definitions ( name, resolve etc )
const queryFields = graphqlSchema.getQueryType().getFields()

// They can then be iterated, and the original `resolve` method can be monkey-patched
for (const queryName in queryFields) {
    const queryInfo = queryFields[queryName]
    // Grab a copy of the original method
    const originalResolve = queryInfo.resolve

    // Overwrite the original `resolve` method 
    queryInfo.resolve = function patchedResolve(src, args, context, info) {
        // Your custom logic goes here
        console.log(info);

        // Call the original `resolve` method, preserving the context and
        // passing in the arguments
        return originalResolve.apply(this, arguments)
    }
}
```